# Plaid Link integration with Back4App

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parse-platform, plaid

New to dev and literally just copied and pasted the plaid link integration(https://plaid.com/docs/#integrating-with-link) right into a basic HTML page for the client side code and right into back4app's cloud code (Node JS) for the server side code and call the function from the cloud but nothing happens and I get these errors:

> 1. Fetch API cannot load file:///create_link_token. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
> 2. index2.html:42 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
>    at fetchLinkToken (index2.html:42)
> 3. parse.min.js:13 POST https://parseapi.back4app.com/functions/plaidAPI 400
> 4. parse.min.js:13 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid function: "plaidAPI"
>    at handleError

My Html code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parse/2.1.0/parse.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .inputs{
      margin: 30px 0px;
    }
    .inputs input{
      margin: 5px 0px;
      height: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
   <div class="title">
     <h1>Test</h1>
   </div>
</div>
<button id="link-button">Link Account</button>
<script src="js/credentials.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/server.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(async function($) {
  const fetchLinkToken = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/create_link_token', { method: 'POST' });
    const responseJSON = await response.json();
    return responseJSON.link_token;
  };

  const configs = {
 
    token: await fetchLinkToken(),
    onLoad: function() {
      // Optional, called when Link loads
    },
    onSuccess: async function(public_token, metadata) {
      
      await fetch('/get_access_token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ public_token: public_token }),
      });
    },
    onExit: async function(err, metadata) {
      // The user exited the Link flow.
      if (err != null) {
        // The user encountered a Plaid API error prior to exiting.
        if (err.error_code === 'INVALID_LINK_TOKEN') {
          
          handler.destroy();
          handler = Plaid.create({
            ...configs,
            token: await fetchLinkToken(),
          });
        }
      }
      
    },
    onEvent: function(eventName, metadata) {
      }
    }
  };

  let handler = Plaid.create(configs);


  $('#link-button').on('click', function(e) {
    handler.open();
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<script id="plaid">
  Parse.Cloud.run("plaidAPI")
  </script>



</body>



</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Cloud Code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var plaid = require('plaid');

// We store the access_token in memory - in production, store it in
// a secure persistent data store.
let ACCESS_TOKEN = null;
let ITEM_ID = null;

const client = new plaid.Client({
  clientID: 'Hidden-For-Obvious-Reasons',
  secret: 'Hidden-For-Obvious-Reasons',
  env: plaid.environments.sandbox
});

const app = express();

// Create a link_token to initialize Link
app.post('/create_link_token', async function(request, response, next) {
  // Grab the client_user_id by searching for the current user in your database
  const user = await User.find(...);
  const clientUserId = user.id;

  // Create the link_token with all of your configurations
  client.createLinkToken({
    user: {
      client_user_id: clientUserId,
    },
    client_name: 'My App',
    products: ['transactions'],
    country_codes: ['US'],
    language: 'en',
    webhook: 'https://sample.webhook.com',
  }, function(error, linkTokenResponse) {
    // Pass the result to your client-side app to initialize Link
    response.json({ link_token: linkTokenResponse.link_token });
  });
});

// Accept the public_token sent from Link
app.post('/get_access_token', function(request, response, next) {
  const public_token = request.body.public_token;
  client.exchangePublicToken(public_token, function(error, response) {
    if (error != null) {
      console.log('Could not exchange public_token!' + '\n' + error);
      return response.json({error: msg});
    }

    // Store the access_token and item_id in your database
    ACCESS_TOKEN = response.access_token;
    ITEM_ID = response.item_id;

    console.log('Access Token: ' + ACCESS_TOKEN);
    console.log('Item ID: ' + ITEM_ID);
    response.json({'error': false});
  });
});
app.listen(8000);
}
```

Comment: You first need to decide if you prefer to create a [cloud code function](https://www.back4app.com/docs/get-started/cloud-functions) or a [custom express route](https://www.back4app.com/docs/js-framework/node-web-server). You are currently creating a custom express route and calling it like it were a cloud code function.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to launch node via the express route instead of calling the cloud code.